# Can't upload Images to MS Sql server via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, image, upload

i'm trying to upload an image to MS SQL web-server in Linux(raspbian) environment using python language. so far i had able connect to MS Sql and also i had create a table. And im using pyodbc.

```
#! /user/bin/env python
import pyodbc 

dsn = 'nicedcn'
user = myid
password = mypass
database = myDB

con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, user, password, database)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

string = "CREATE TABLE Database1([image name] varchar(20), [image] varbinary(max))"
cursor.execute(string)
cnxn.commit()
```

this part complied without any error. that means i have successfully created a table isn't? or is there any issue?

i try to upload image as this way.

```
with open('new1.jpg','rb') as f:
            bindata = f.read()
cursor.execute("insert into Database1(image name, image) values (?,?)", 'new1', bindata)
cnxn.commit()
```

i get the error on this part. and it pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [FreeTDS] [SQL Server] Satement(s) could not be prepared. (8180) (SQLParamData)')

can some one help me please. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters must be passed in as *one* sequence, not as two separate arguments. A tuple will do nicely here:

```
cursor.execute(
    "insert into Database1([image name], image) values (?,?)",
    ('new1', pyodbc.Binary(bindata)))
```

Note that you also need to quote the `image name` column correctly, and wrap the data in a `pyodbc.Binary()` object; this will produce the right datatype for your Python version (`bytearray` or `bytes`).

Comment: thank for you help but i'm still getting that same error

Comment: @Kevin777: ah, yes, your `image name` column also needs quoting.

Comment: thanks for you help. i think it works but i'm still getting error. it says pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('22018', '[22018] [FreeTDS] [SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with varbinary(max)  (206) (SQLParamData)')... 

do i need to change my image coloum data type into image or blob? can i upload image as jpg directly in to the database??

Comment: @Kevin777: right, you need to use a `pyodbc.Binary()` object.

Comment: sir there is another issue,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491421/cant-insert-date-and-time-to-sql-server-via-pyodbc/24492737?noredirect=1#comment37915225_24492737
help me please