# Can't insert Date and Time to sql server via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql, date, time, pyodbc

I'm trying to insert date and time to SQL server in Linux (raspbian) environment using python language.So far i was able connect to MS Sql and also i created a table and im using pyodbc.

```
#! /user/bin/env python
import pyodbc 
import datetime

dsn = 'nicedcn'
user = myid
password = mypass
database = myDB

con_string = 'DSN=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;DATABASE=%s;' % (dsn, user, password, database)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_string)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

string = "CREATE TABLE Database3([row name] varchar(20), [my date] date), [my time]    time)"
cursor.execute(string)
cnxn.commit()
```

This part complied without any error.That means i have successfully created a table right? Or is there any issue?

I try to add date and time this way.

```
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
    d1 = now.date()
    t2 = now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    cursor.execute("insert into Database3([row name], [my date], [my time]) values (?,?,?)", 
    ('new1', d1, t2))
    cnxn.commit()
```

But i get this error. pyodbc.ProgrammingError:

> ('HY004', '[HY004] [FreeTDS] [SQL Server]Invalid data type (O)
>   (SQLBindParameter)')

help me please. thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with python but have you tried with colons instead of dashes for the time `"%H:%M:%S"`?

Comment: What version of the SQL Server native client are you using?

Comment: I'm Using MS SQL 2008 R2 Express

Comment: "%H:%M:%S" yes i tried this but i get the same result

Comment: @Kevin777 2008 R2 Express is the version of SQL Server you are using, not the version of the ODBC driver. What version of the ODBC driver for SQL Server is used in your DSN? This can be found using the [ODBC Data Source Administrator](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ngj4m.png).

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm using UnixODBC

Comment: and also i had use FreeTDS to establish the connection. and also pyodbc

Comment: I'm still learning. i think the answer is pyodbc

Comment: FreeTDS version is what matters. I'm not familiar with using FreeTDS, and don't know what version supports the `date` and `time` types in SQL Server. See the link to Microsoft's ODBC driver that has support for these types in my answer.

Comment: IT is TDS 7.1(8.0 before) and it supported for SQL Server 2000. Includes support for big integer (64-bit int) and "variant" datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Windows, install the latest version of the [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to ensure the `DATE` and `TIME` types are supported.

If you are on Linux or macOS, use this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/system-requirements?view=sql-server-2017) to determine the latest driver available for your distribution.

Use parameter placeholders and pass the values as [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date) and [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) objects for the current datetime value.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
sql = "insert into Database3([row name], [my date], [my time]) values (?,?,?)"
cursor.execute(sql, ('new1', now.date(), now.time()))
cnxn.commit()
```

Note that the above code was only tested on Windows.

Comment: I'm on Linux (raspberry pi)

Comment: @Kevin777 Updated with link to documentation for Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux

Comment: if there is any issue with my data types ??

Comment: `date` and `time` datatypes were introduced in SQL Server 2008. Upgrade FreeTDS to the latest version, or use the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux.