# How to update datetime field in MSSQL using python pyodbc module

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime, pyodbc

I am trying to update the DB table using `convert(datetime,'19-01-16 11:34:09 PM',5)`, but when I pass this as string to insert into DB table I'm getting the data type conversion error.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
insert into Run (RunID, StartDate) 
values ('19012016',"convert(datetime,'19-01-16 11:34:09 PM',5)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an error because you are passing treating it as a string value.  Instead:

```
insert into Run(RunID, StartDate) 
    values ('19012016', convert(datetime, '19-01-16 11:34:09 PM', 5))
```

That is, you had too many quotes.  In Python, this would typically be written as:

```
"""insert into Run(RunID, StartDate) 
    values ('19012016', convert(datetime, '19-01-16 11:34:09 PM', 5))"""
```

If you want to insert values:

```
"""insert into Run(RunID, StartDate) 
    values ('{0}', convert(datetime, '{1}', 5))""".format("19012016", "19-01-16 11:34:09 PM")
```

I would suggest that you use a more common format such as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, if you have a choice of date representation.

Comment: Im trying to update using python script, 
cur=con.cursor()
cur.execute(insert into Run (RunID, StartDate) values ('19012016',"convert(datetime,'19-01-16 11:34:09 PM',5)"))

If I remove the quotes ("), I will get error as-  NameError: global name 'convert' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Converting string values to datetime values using T-SQL can be error-prone, especially if you have to consider different locales and timezones.

Instead of using T-SQL for the conversion, use [parameters](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/GettingStarted#Parameters) with native [Python datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html) values. Python offers more flexibility with [datetime parsing and formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) than T-SQL.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24492737/366335) for an example for using Python datetime values with pyodbc parameters.