# Search and Update datetime column with given time in mssql+pyodbc and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have been using `MSSQL` and `pyodbc` and updating a column with `DateTime` type by following the below thread:

[How to update datetime field in MSSQL using python pyodbc module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915505/how-to-update-datetime-field-in-mssql-using-python-pyodbc-module)

Now I am also trying to incorporate `sqlalchemy` in my application stack. I am aware of following answer but it does not serve my purpose.

[Datetime not updating on insert using SQLAlchemy on MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451356/datetime-not-updating-on-insert-using-sqlalchemy-on-mssql)

To elaborate on the problem:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, DateTime, Date
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from datetime import datetime as datetimemodule, date as datemodule
import traceback

BASE = declarative_base()

class REPR:

    def make_repr(self, **kwrgs):

        argument_string = ', '.join([f'{a}={b}' for a, b in locals()['kwrgs'].items()])
        display_string = f'{self.__class__.__name__}({argument_string})'
        return '*****' +  display_string + '*****'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

class Recog_EntryLog(BASE, REPR):

    # In database corresponding table has no primary key.
    # As suggested in the documentation, largest candidate key is marked as
    # primary key here.

    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    entrytime = Column(DateTime, primary_key=True) # I want to update this field by custom defined time.
                                                   # Not by the entry update time.
    entrydate = Column(Date, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.make_repr(id=self.id, entrytime=self.entrytime, entrydate=self.entrydate)

def get_connection(dbname):
    connection_info = f'mssql+pyodbc://remote:prashant@127.0.0.1:1433/{dbname}?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
    engine = create_engine(connection_info, echo=True)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()

    return session, engine

def close_connection(connection_info:sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session, 
                     engine:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine):

    connection_info.close()
    engine.dispose()

def search_and_update(connected_session:sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session, 
                    id,
                    _time:datetimemodule,
                    _date:datemodule):

    res = connected_session.query(Recog_EntryLog).filter_by(id=id, entrydate=_date).order_by(Recog_EntryLog.entrytime.desc()).first()
    print(res)
    try:
        if res is None:
            connected_session.add(Recog_EntryLog(id=id, entrytime=_time, entrydate=_date))
        else:
            query = connected_session.query(Recog_EntryLog).filter_by(id=id, entrytime=res.entrytime, entrydate=_date)
            query.update({Recog_EntryLog.entrytime: _time})

        connected_session.commit()
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        connected_session.rollback()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    connected_session, connected_engine = get_connection('authentication')

    # Will create new entry on first run/Will update old entry
    search_and_update(connected_session, '1234', datetimemodule.now(), datemodule.today()) 

    # should update datetime
    search_and_update(connected_session, '1234', datetimemodule.now(), datemodule.today()) 

    # should update datetime
    search_and_update(connected_session, '1234', datetimemodule.now(), datemodule.today()) 

    close_connection(connected_session, connected_engine)
```

[image: Last two red values were supposed to be updated with the first two blue values.]

I was expecting that last two red values will be updated with the first two blue values. Generated SQL does not seem to follow first attach link sql.

Can some help me how to properly write such function using sqlalchemy?

Comment: `entrytime=res.entrytime` probably has a rounding issue: it is unlikely the *exact* same time is present in the database. I suggest you find a different way of expressing that filter

Comment: Why aren't you simply doing `res.entrytime = _time` instead of trying to select again and updating that (potentially set of) record(s)?