# Operand type clash with parameterized UPDATE query

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-2.7, pyodbc

I have a SQL Server table with the following columns (* indicates NULLs are allowed):

- ID (int)
- RequisitionID (int)
- ApplicantID (int)
- WorkflowStateID (int)
- WorkflowDate (datetime)
- SubmissionDate (datetime)
- StartDate (date)*
- DispositionID (int)*
- ATSApplicationID (varchar(255))*
- ApplicationLink (varchar(255))*
- CreateDate (datetime)
- ModifyDate (datetime)

I am attempting a parameterized INSERT query using pypyodbc with Driver=SQL Server (MS SQL Server 2012 database). Here is the query:

```
sql_statement = """
    UPDATE [hr].[ATS.Applications] SET RequisitionID = ?, WorkflowStateID = ?, WorkflowDate = ?, StartDate = ?, DispositionID = ?, ModifyDate = ? WHERE ID = ?
    """

cursor.execute(sql_statement,(new_application.requisition_id,
                              new_application.workflow_state,
                              new_application.workflow_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
                              new_start_date,
                              new_application.disposition,
                              now,
                              old_application.ID))

cursor.commit()
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
DataError: (u'22018', u'[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date')
```

I assume one of the date strings is being interpreted as a calculated integer, however using the debugger, all data & data types appear to be compatible with my table:

```
new_application.requisition_id = {int} 7
new_application.workflow_state = {int} 19
new_application.workflow_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") = {str} '2017-05-09T07:52:13'
new_start_date = {NoneType} None
new_application.disposition = {int} 7
now = {str} '2017-05-09T17:55:27'
old_application.ID = {int} 34402
```

I've tried inserting datetime values as both datetime objects and strings, and 
can't seem to resolve what data type it's expecting.

Any ideas why I am having issues with this UPDATE statement?

Comment: can you provide resultant query?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! By resultant query do you mean the SQL query with all '?' replaced with the values? My debugger cannot show this with how the code is written, as the parameters are being replaced upon query execute.

Comment: I still receive the same error "int is incompatible with date." I assume both the "now" and "workflow_date" could be causing the issue here. It seems to be really finicky with what format it accepts datetime values -- I've tried as type datetime and as type string and can't figure out which way is correct.

Comment: which database driver are you using? there definitely should be support of converting `datetime` objects for query bindings

Comment: I'm using Driver={SQL Server}. I've had this working successfully in the past but didn't understand why. Now that the issue has come up again I'm hoping to get a better understanding of the failure.

Comment: why are you inserting `None` value for `new_start_date`?

Comment: Sometimes it is None sometimes it is not None. I'm not sure if that is affecting the issue here. This is the closest thread I have found to helping:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i

Comment: have you tried execute query with all bindings set, without `?` characters? or a simple query without datetime fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `pypyodbc` handle the type conversion from Python [date](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects)/[datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) objects to the appropriate SQL Server data type, instead of relying on string formatting.

In the example below, I'm assuming:

- `new_application.workflow_date` is Python datetime object
- `now` from original question is intended to get current system time using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#) module

```
sql_statement = """
UPDATE [hr].[ATS.Applications] SET RequisitionID = ?, WorkflowStateID = ?, WorkflowDate = ?, StartDate = ?, DispositionID = ?, ModifyDate = ? WHERE ID = ?
    """

cursor.execute(sql_statement,(new_application.requisition_id,
                              new_application.workflow_state,
                              new_application.workflow_date,
                              new_start_date,
                              new_application.disposition,
                              datetime.now(),
                              old_application.ID))

cursor.commit()
```

For a supporting example including SQL Server `DATE` and `TIME` types see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24492737/366335).

Comment: I removed "new_start_date" from the query and it worked. This variable was being converted from a date object to a string object using .strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), which was being interpreted as an integer (i.e. 2017 minus 5 minus 10).